# mongodb find documents where document has other than ID

Tags: mongodb

My document structure is something

```
{
   _id: name,
   dynamicDoc: {
     _id: id,
     fields....
   }
}
```

I want to get all the dynamic docs for a name where dynamic doc has fields other than _id.

```
{
  _id: "jack",
  order1:{
    _id: order897776,
    item names....
  },
  order2:{
    _id:order22789
  }
}
```

I want to getorder1 for jack as order doesn't have orders. order1 is a dynamic field.

Comment: An example to clarify the problem would be great

Comment: @chridam Please find the some dummy example

Comment: I feel the modeling of the document should be different like have `orders array` and then have objects inside it like `[{_id:"order897776", item_names:{name:item1}}, {_id:order22789}]`   it would look like `{_id:"jack", "orders:[{_id:"order897776", item_names:{name:item1}}, {_id:order22789}] }`

Comment: I also think you should not use `_id`inside of a document that is already having `_id` for document id, instead you can use `id` in sub documents. In this case that array of `orders`

Answer (score 1):

One way to get around this is to run an aggregate pipeline that gets data about the keys at the root level of the document,
denoted by the system variable [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT), run through their values and determine whether they have more than one key.

For the first step, use [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) add an extra field that holds the above computations and use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to convert 
the key/value pairs to an array of `[ { k: 'key name': v: 'value' }, ... ]`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$addFields': {
        'myKeys': { '$objectToArray': '$$ROOT' }
    } }
])
```

On getting this array, the next step will be to iterate the list and convert the values field to an array. 
This is necessary to then filter the values by comparing the size of the array, if it has more than one element then that's your guy

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$addFields': {
        'myKeys': { 
            '$map': {
                'input': { '$objectToArray': '$$ROOT' },
                'in': {
                    'k': '$$this.k',
                    'v': {
                        '$cond': [ // condition to convert the _id key value in ROOT to a single element array
                            { '$eq': ['$$this.k', '_id'] },
                            ['$$this.v'],
                            { '$objectToArray': '$$this.v' } // convert the rest of the keys at ROOT
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

Filtering uses the results from the previous pipeline and checking the array size:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$addFields': {
        'myKeys': { 
            '$map': {
                'input': { '$objectToArray': '$$ROOT' },
                'in': {
                    'k': '$$this.k',
                    'v': {
                        '$cond': [ // condition to convert the _id key value in ROOT to a single element array
                            { '$eq': ['$$this.k', '_id'] },
                            ['$$this.v'],
                            { '$objectToArray': '$$this.v' } // convert the rest of the keys at ROOT
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } },
    { '$addFields':{ 
        'myKeys': {
            '$filter': {
                'input': '$myKeys',
                'as': 'el',
                'cond': { 
                    '$gt': [{ '$size': '$$this.v'}, 1]
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

This can be reduced to a single pipeline but verbosity is reduced:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$addFields':{ 
        'myKeys': {
            '$filter': {
                'input': { 
                    '$map': {
                        'input': { '$objectToArray': '$$ROOT' },
                        'in': {
                            'k': '$$this.k',
                            'v': {
                                '$cond': [
                                    { '$eq': ['$$this.k', '_id'] },
                                    ['$$this.v'],
                                    { '$objectToArray': '$$this.v' }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                'as': 'el',
                'cond': { 
                    '$gt': [{ '$size': '$$el.v'}, 1]
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```